# VueJS - pass properties from one component to another in the template

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm new to Vue, and am trying to build up a set of business components that rely on other lower-level components, and pass properties to them.  None of the usual data-binding v-bind:propName="xxx" or :propName="xxx" seem to work from inside a component template however, and all the documentation treats prop passing from a top-level HTML page instead of from one component to another.

For example, with the below I have a lower-level component called "exchange-panel" which takes a "title" property.  I want my higher-level component to use that generic exchange-panel and pass in a title to use.  I get the following error:

```
[Vue warn]: Error compiling template:

        <exchange-panel :title="The Panel Title">
            <h1>test</h1>
        </exchange-panel>    


- invalid expression: :title="The Panel Title"


found in

---> <OrderbookDetail>
```

Here is the sample code (also at https://jsfiddle.net/ns1km8fh/

```
Vue.component("orderbook-detail", {
    template:`
        <exchange-panel :title="Public order book">
            <h1>test</h1>
        </exchange-panel>    
    `
});
Vue.component("exchange-panel", {
    template:`
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Title: {{ title }}</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <slot></slot>
            </div>
        </div>`,
    props: ["title"]
})

new Vue({
    el: "#exchange-container",
    created: function () {
        window.Vue = this
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to quote `Public order book`.

```
 <exchange-panel :title="'Public order book'">
```

The value of a bound attribute is treated as a javascript expression. Javascript strings need to be enclosed in quotes of some kind (single, double, backticks).

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ns1km8fh/1/).

As @RoyJ points out, you can also simply not bind it and use it as a normal attribute.

```
 <exchange-panel title="Public order book">
```

Comment: or remove the colon before `title` so it's a literal prop rather than an interpreted one.

Comment: @RoyJ True. Updated.

Comment: I was missing the "attribute is treated as a javascript expression" - that fix worked perfectly.  Thank you